# 英語が残っている+日本語に違和感: 自分の質問に自分で回答する時に出るダイアログ: Yes, I want to post an answer

Tags: バグ, 完了, 翻訳, 日本語, 英語

[image: Yes, I want to post an answer]

Comment: 「はい、回答したい」でいいですか？

Comment: @jmac ダイアログの他の文言も含めて、修正案を回答として投稿しました。確認おねがいします

Comment: 今ボタンのテックスは「本当に自分の質問に回答しますか？」になって、間違ってるじゃないか？とにかく、これの[transifexのリンク](https://www.transifex.com/projects/p/stack-overflow-ja/translate/#ja/english/40289545?reviewed=no)

Answer (score 4):

**本当に自分の質問に回答しますか？**

他の人の回答に返信したい場合は、その回答に**コメント**してください。  
質問に補足情報を追加したい場合は、質問を**編集**できます。

回答の投稿を続行します